# Using cell value as part of VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have working code where there are sheet names that need to be updated periodically.

Is there a way the code can pull the sheet name from a cell. That way I can type the sheet name into a cell and the code will reference that.

So instead of typing in the sheet name "Hello" for example, it would just reference the cell "F20" to get that cell value.

Answer (score 0):

Should be

```
ActiveSheet.Cells(20, 6).Value
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can,

```
ActiveSheet.Name = Range("F20")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the cell value containing Sheet name to a variable and then use that Variable to select the sheet. For multiple sheets you can use the loop to select and take action.

```
Sub test()
   shtName = Range("A1")
   Sheets(shtName).Select
End Sub
```